# How to disable user Interaction during AVAudioSession

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I am currently working on a method that will play a mp4 file when called.  However, while the mp4 file is being played I want user interactions to be disabled. This is so that the user cannot tap the screen while the mp4 is playing and start the same AVAudioSession over again. My code thus far is this

```
import Foundation; import UIKit; import AVFoundation

var player: AVAudioPlayer?

class Card: NSObject
{
var image: UIImage
var soundUrl: String


init(image: UIImage, soundUrl: String, isActive:Bool = true) {
    self.image = image
    self.soundUrl = soundUrl
}
func playSound()
{
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: self.soundUrl, withExtension: "m4a") else { return }
    do
    {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        guard let player = player else { return }
        player.prepareToPlay()

        player.play()

        print("play")
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Disable certain elements or disable all incoming touches on the device?

Comment: disable all incoming touches on the device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing any references to the UI elements you want to disable. You're just going to set `button.isEnabled = false` on the them, and set them back when the player is done. You'll know the player is done by setting your object as its `delegate` and then implementing `func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_:successfully)` to turn things back on.

As a note, there is never a reason to call `prepareToPlay()` immediately before calling `play()`. `play()` prepares itself.

---

```
player.delegate = self

extension Card: AVAudioPlayerDelegate  {
    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool)
        // re-enable UI
    }
}
```

Comment: 'You'll know the player is done by setting your object as its delegate'  how exactly would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` after playing the audio.

After that, use `self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` on `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_:successfully)`

Answer (score 1):

To disable all incoming touches on the device, you can call `UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()` and call `UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()` to reenable touches. This is typically called during animations but this is what you asked for.